# Get Parameter from a URL Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView to navigate in internet in my app.
How i can get parameter from a url when i try to login in a page ?..

For example i have form in HTML, with username and password parameter, the complete url is:
mysite/?username=48djdui&password=fdsajfo

but, how i can get this parameter? and take this url?

Sorry for my english..

The code for now is:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

 webView.loadUrl(inputurl);
```

Comment: Do you want to extract the parameters from the url?

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
String url = "http://www.yourdomain.com/?param1=ONE&param2=TWO";
List<NameValuePair> parameters = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url));
for (NameValuePair param: parameters) {
    String name = param.getName();
    String value = param.getValue();
}
```

Or this

```
Uri url = Uri.parse(webView.getUrl());
Set<String> paramNames = url.getQueryParameterNames();
for (String key: paramNames) {
    String value = url.getQueryParameter(key);
}
```

Comment: after webView.loadUrl(inputurl);  ?

Comment: You can get the address from the webView or also you can create the url object with input url (prefer the second one)

Comment: That snippet is valid only if your web view has an url already wetted. If not take that url from your inputurl object

Comment: i try this snipped i put in the onPageStarted method, i navigate and when i have the login form i put the user and pass and click on the button in the page, but url.getQueryParameterNames() have no parameters..

Comment: Try with the new snippet. This one should work. I tried both two and both work well.

Comment: if i try with browser, i have www.site/login/ and when i click i go to see the information network and i have still www.site/login and in the form data i have my parameters.. i try the new snippent, but where i put that? in the onPageStarted ?

Comment: i have this error in URLEncodeUtils:  The method parse(HttpEntity) in the type URLEncodedUtils is not applicable for the arguments (URI)

Comment: i try but form my website not work because i don't have www.site.com/?user=dsa&pass=fdsa but i have www.site.com/

Comment: I do not understand why you need to extract parameters if there are not parameters in your url

Comment: because i have this login form in website that i want to get parameters, not the value, but the data form request.. this login have a parameters btnlogin=&user=&pass= i want to get btnlogin,user and pass..if i try your snipped i have url=www.site.com/ never parameters..so how i can get btnlogin user and pass? sorry for my english

Comment: You can try using webView.getOriginalUrl() rather than getUrl() (given that I have understood your problem :))

Answer (score 2):

```
val url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=25&since=1374196005"
val sanitizer = UrlQuerySanitizer(url)
sanitizer.getValue("limit")
```

Make use of class called `UrlQuerySanitizer`. It can also give you list of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the getUrl function of WebView.

```
String url = webView.getUrl();
```

This function returns a String, you can use this String to exract the parameters.

See here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl%28%29